# Is Google Play Services GPS accurate enough?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I am trying to work out the possibility of detecting a person walking through GPS.

I am currently using GooglePlayServices to locate the user, however, I need to work out if the GPS is accurate enough to detect a person walking about 5m/s to 10m/s.

Is the GPS accurate enough? Or will I have to use another method of finding the speed?

Comment: You can always test it to know it!

Comment: Currently, I've a simple app that uses the distance, though the speed is so minuscule that I'm not quite sure if it's GPS accuracy or a bug in the programming.

Comment: I think GooglePlayServices is your best option as of now. Reading from [Making Your App Location-Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), developers are highly encouraged to switch to Google Play services GPS. In this [GPS video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xwKQa9Tm5k), Fused Location Provider can combine information using GPS, cell tower, and Wi-Fi signals to accurately determine position.